# MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER while using certificate to authenticate

Tags: ssl, openssl, pfx

I am trying to authenticate against an API using certs.

I have a pfx file that I need to convert to required certs.

In order to generate the Public cert, i used the command :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ~/Downloads/file.pfx -nodes -clcerts -nokeys | openssl x509 -out public.crt
```

This public cert was uploaded on the API side.

Now from the client side I need to connect to the api using `curl`

So first I generated the Private Key using the command :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ~/Downloads/file.pfx -nodes -nocerts | openssl rsa -out private_new.key
```

And now Im trying to connect to the API using the command :

```
curl -I -k --key ./private_new.key --cert ./public.crt https://<API-END-POINT>/foo/bar
```

But in the response I get :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2019 00:24:43 GMT
Server: Foo
X-IDS-ID: 4E178F65-78F2-4CB9-B31A-8D6288F854C5
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=CPS Rest Services
X-message-code: MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: X-CSP-STRIP
X-IDS-Node: idp15
X-IDS-Pool: green
X-IDS-Project: prod
X-IDS-Landscape: eu-nl-1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload
Cache-Control: private,no-cache,no-store
```

Is there something I have missed ? Im new to this so Im not sure what I might have missed.

Answer (score 2):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
...
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=CPS Rest Services
X-message-code: MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER
```

The API requires a proper [Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) header within your request but you don't send one. It is unclear what the contents should be but usually there is some username and password encoded together.

There is nothing known about the API you are trying to access so no help is possible on how to use it properly:

- Specifically it is not known if the site has authentication using a client certificate at all. If it doesn't then you can't enforce it.
- If it supports client certificates then it might find your self-generated certificate not sufficient since there is no way to verify who is behind this certificate. In this case it might try with Basic Authentication as a fallback to the failed client certificate.
- It might also be that the site needs Basic Authentication in addition to a client certificate.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I also add basic authentication (username:password) in addition to sending the client cert and private key from client side ?

Comment: @JasonStanley: you could try that. But it would be better if you made yourself familiar with what the API really requires (documentation?) and if you need help also provide the necessary information about the API. Currently it  just guessing of what the API might require.

Comment: The only information I have is `"TLS Client Certificate authentication (RFC 5246)
Use of the API requires client authentication as part of the TLS handshake of the HTTPS transport channel."` Im still looking around to find more info. Hopefully I can get to the root of this.